`req.session.user` does not save
After user logs in, some information about the user is saved in req.session.user, like his id,username and role
But verifyUser middleware always returns status 401 because it thinks that req.session.user is undefined
Login route
router.post("/",... , async (req,res) => {
    ...
    // Authenticate the user
    req.session.user= {
      id: user._id.toString(),
      username: username,
      role: user.role,
    };
    console.log("User logged in and session.user is");
    console.log(req.session.user); // NOTE: This logs correctly
    req.session.save();
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "User logged in successfully.",
      info: { id: user._id, username: username, role: user.role },
    });
})

verifyUser middleware
const verifyUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.session.id); // NOTE: Always different
    console.log(req.session.user); // NOTE: Always undefined
    if (!req.session.user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Log in again." });
    }
    req.userId = req.session.user.id;
    req.userRole = req.session.user.role;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "Error in the server"});
  }
};
module.exports = verifyUser;

Here is the express-session and how it's defined
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
    secure: !process.env.UNSECURE_COOKIES, // Use secure cookies in production
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
// ...

And these are corsOptions also:
// CORS middleware function to check the origin against the allowed list
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // For legacy browser support
};

This is also how user logs in, it just send fetch request and then redirects
   const response = await fetch(`${url}/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });

And this is how user is authenticated on routes that need authentication:
window.getUsers = async function () {
  const reqOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
  };
  try {
    const data = await fetch(`${url}/users/all`, reqOptions);
    const result = await data.json();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert("Error connecting.");
  }
};

PR: https://github.com/Cro-Cube-Comp/Cubing-competition/pull/29
Github branch: https://github.com/Cro-Cube-Comp/Cubing-competition/tree/session-auth
I added console.log(req.session.user) into the /login route after user is authenticated, it logged correctly.
I also added that log in verifyUser middleware, and it always logged undefined
I added console.log(req.session.id) in verifyUser middleware and it logged something different every time
Server is hosted on http://localhost:3000 and my website is on http://localhost:2500

The error was in verifyUser middleware. It is not supposed to be async.

It looks like you're encountering an issue with the session not being accessible across different requests in your Express application, particularly in the verifyUser middleware. Here are a few things to check and consider:

Session Configuration

Your session configuration looks mostly correct, but ensure that you're using express-session properly and that you're not instantiating it multiple times. Make sure the middleware is applied in the right order.

Usage of req.session.save()

In your login route, the statement req.session.save(); is executed after setting the session user. This should be awaited since it’s an asynchronous operation. Without awaiting it, your session might not be properly saved before the response is sent. Update your login route to:
await req.session.save();


Verify User Middleware Order

Ensure that your verifyUser middleware is applied after your session middleware. The middleware should look something like this:
app.use(session({...}));  // Your session configuration
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(verifyUser);  // Ensure this is below session middleware


CORS Credentials

You’ve enabled CORS with credentials, which is good. Just make sure the client sending the request is set to credentials: 'include' (which you've done in your fetch request). This allows cookies (which include the session ID) to be sent.

Check Session Store Emulation

If you're using a specific session store (like connect-mongodb-session or similar), ensure the store is configured properly. Without it, req.session may not hold the expected data.

Debugging Logs

If req.session is undefined in your middleware but defined in your routes, check the following:

Log the entire session object: console.log(req.session); in both the login route and the middleware to see if there are any discrepancies.
Ensure that you're not accidentally creating a new session in your middleware. This might happen if the session store is misconfigured or if there's some unintended behavior in your middleware function.


Client-Side State

If you're on the client side and making requests to the API, ensure that no other action (like a page refresh) is leading to the loss of session data. Try checking the network tab to confirm whether cookies are sent with each request.
Example Adjusted Login Route
Here’s how your adjusted login route might look:
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
...
// Authenticate the user
req.session.user = {
    id: user._id.toString(),
    username: username,
    role: user.role,
};
console.log("User logged in and session.user is");
console.log(req.session.user); // This will log correctly
await req.session.save(); // Ensure this is awaited
res.status(200).json({
    message: "User logged in successfully.",
    info: { id: user._id, username: username, role: user.role },
});

});


I made sure to declare it correctly
req.session.save is not async function and it will not change the result
I verified
I did make sure
Store is not changed so it's using express-session default
req.session exists, but req.session.user does not

